# Number of movies rated by each user

Tags: hive

There are two tables.
1st table contains columns `id`, `name`, `year` &
2nd table contains columns `userid`, `movieid`, `rating`:

id = primary key &
movieid = foreign key

> SELECT COUNT (movie_table.name) FROM movie_table INNER JOIN movierating_table ON movie_table.id=movierating_table.movieid id where (userid=1500, 2000);

I want number of movies rated by each user. Each user get by:

> select DISTINCT userid from movierating_table;

Comment: SO is a Q&A platform and you haven't asked a question. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of movies rated by each user, you can use a GROUP BY clause along with the COUNT function. Here's the SQL query to achieve that:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(movieid) AS num_movies_rated
FROM movierating_table
GROUP BY userid;
```

If you want to retrieve only the distinct user IDs from the movierating_table, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM movierating_table;
```